# hypervisor.cpuid.v0 or hidden state='on' equivlent in hyper-v

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019, passthrough, nvidia

I'd like to hide to a vm, that it's being virtualized on hyper-v. I've done:

ExposeVirtualizationExtensions : True

But it doesn't seem to have the same effect. The goal is to pass a nvidia geforce 1080 to a linux vm for the purpose of tensorflow. I've successfully done the passthrough, and it shows in lspci, but nvidia-smi returns "Unable to determine the device handle for GPU". In windows I believe this manifests it's self as error 43. KVM and Vmware handle this by simply hiding that the system is virtualized. This fixes the issue in both windows and ubuntu on either virtualization platform.